# Android - Dynamically set intent Extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass an ID to my new activity on creation.

The obvious solution seems to be to use "Intent.putExtra(name, value);". 
But as the intent is only created on click, all of my buttons have the same Intent extras (useally null).

Is there any way i can initialize these from a loop?

```
for ( int i = 0; i< IDList.size() ; i++) 
    {
        //Get Information from ID

        btnDetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("", IDList.get(i));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Add To Screen
    }
```

In the code snippit IDList.get(i) is out of scope and a new Final Int isn't checked until the button is clicked, also going out of scope.

Is there any other was i can send the variable on click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can a inner class that implements OnClickListener and takes as parameter the id. For instance

```
 private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
  private final int mId;
  public MyOnClickListener(int id) {
    mId = id;
  }

  public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("", mId);
      startActivity(intent);
   }

} 

 for ( int i = 0; i< IDList.size() ; i++)   {       
        btnDetails.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(IDList.get(i)));
 }
```

Comment: Had to tweak the code to also pass the activity as "GetApplicationContext()" Is now out of scope, but other than that worked like a charm. Cheers!

Comment: Add context as parameter to the constructor of MyOnClickListener